# How to run an android app on the device with ant

Tags: android, ant

I would like to be able to launch my app after installation with ant just as happens when pressing the `run` button in eclipse.

Is there an existing ant task after creating a project on the command line or is there a command I could execute with ant?

Comment: +1 Really good question. I've automated my whole `compile -> install` process using a combination of `ant` and a `makefile` and the only piece missing is _launching_ the app within the emulator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

executing `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n <Package_name>/.<Activity>` from ant should launch your app.ofcourse you need to build and install the app trying to start the app...you can use android build xml to build and use "adb install " to install the app...

Answer (score 32):

Using the command provided by Navin I was able to create this ant target:

```
<target name="run">
    <exec executable="adb">
        <arg value="shell"/>
        <arg value="am"/>
        <arg value="start"/>
        <arg value="-a"/>
        <arg value="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <arg value="-n"/>
        <arg value="{package.name}/{activity}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

On the command line I execute:

```
ant debug install run
```

And it all works swimmingly.

**EDIT**

As WarrenFaith helpfully pointed out in the comments `{activity}` should be the class name of main activity with a `.` prefix.

So a complete example of the value of the last arg would be

```
org.package.name/.MyCustomActivity
```

Comment: for everybody struggling like me: Don't forget that the `{activity}` MUST start with a `.` (a dot!). Sample: `org.package.name/.MyCustomActivity`

Comment: Nice idea zode64 :-) Also, to restart an app from scratch you can use the command "adb shell am force-stop <PACKAGE_NAME>", maybe you should add it to the ant target?

Comment: This fails if there are multiple devices connected. Is there any way to get it to prompt you which device to install it on?

Comment: @karl When you execute ant you could try `ant -Dadb.device.arg="-s emulator-5554" -e install run` or whatever the name is of the device (from here http://blog.duzy.info/2011/09/android-ant-install-to-specific-device.html). Let me know if it works.

Comment: @zode64 I could specify the device, but I would have to know the name of it and keep that in my codebase, and then I would have to change it for each device. Is there a way to get it to install on all connected devices?

Comment: @karl The feature seems to have been to eclipse added here - https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/37380/ but it doesn't look available through the CL (perhaps you can do a bit of digging to find out). Short of that, you could create a script that gets all connected android devices and then runs the ant task on each one but it would be a bit messy.

Comment: @zode64 Is there a way in ANT to prompt for user input? Worst case, I could run adb devices, echo the results, and then ask the user to pick one.

Comment: @karl This looks like it might help - http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html If you are getting the device names manually another option would be to use a shell script to drive adb and only call ant once you have the device name (passing it as an argument). Also I think it is work chasing up on a google group about the feature I referenced above or ask another question on SO as it would simplify what you are doing quite substantially.

Answer (score 13):

Generally, copy following target to your build.xml or custom_rules.xml.  Note that in custom_rules.xml (if it doesn't yet exist) you need to wrap this in a  element.

```
<target name="start">
    <xpath input="AndroidManifest.xml"
           expression="/manifest/@package"
           output="manifest.package" />
    <xpath input="AndroidManifest.xml"
           expression="/manifest/application/activity[intent-filter/action/@android:name='android.intent.action.MAIN']/@android:name"
           output="manifest.main" />
    <echo level="info">Restart main activity ${manifest.package}/.${manifest.main}</echo>
    <exec executable="${android.platform.tools.dir}/adb">
        <arg value="shell"/>
        <arg value="am"/>
        <arg value="start"/>
        <arg value="-S"/>
        <arg value="-a"/>
        <arg value="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <arg value="-n"/>
        <arg value="${manifest.package}/.${manifest.main}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: This answer is better than the one provided by zode64 because it most tightly integrates with android project format.

Answer (score 0):

```
<target name="run">
    <exec executable="adb">
        <arg value="shell"/>
        <arg value="am"/>
        <arg value="start"/>
        <arg value="-a"/>
        <arg value="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <arg value="-n"/>
        <arg value="{package.name}/{activity}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

I just want to say that `{package.name}` should be equal to `<manifest>`'s `package` and `{activity}` should be the full qualified name of the main activity (i.e. with its package name, e.g. com.example.activty.MainActivty).